# Asymptotic behavior of an integral involving the product of two positive terms

Tags: convergence-divergence, asymptotics, improper-integrals

Let $I(x)$ be the integral defined as
$$I(x) = \int_\mathbb{R} g(x,t) h(x, t) \;dt$$
Assume that for all $x$: the quantity $I(x)$ exists and is finite and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x,t) \; dt$ as well.
The functions $g$ and $h$ are two real functions $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that:

- For all $x,t$: $g(x,t)>0$ and $h(x,t)>0$.
- For all $t$: $x \mapsto h(x, t)$ is non-decreasing.
- For all $t$: $\underset{x \to \infty}{\lim} h(x, t) = 1$.
- For all $t$: $g(x, t) h(x, t) \underset{x \to \infty}{\sim} f(x, t)$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x, t) \; dt$ exists and is finite.

Question: can we conclude
$$
I(x) \underset{x \to \infty}{\sim} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x, t) \; dt\quad?
$$
If yes, why? If not, what are the missing conditions?
I tried using monotone or dominated convergence theorems, but I did not succeed.

Thanks

Comment: I would expect there to be a counterexample unless you also assume that the asymptotics in the third and fourth bullet points hold uniformly for all $t \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks Antonio, But even if I assume uniform convergence, I do not see how to conclude.